# deleteOne, findOneandDelete, findOneandremove are all deleting two documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose and mongodb 4.2.8 and Node.js 14.4.0. I am trying to find the first document with the correct first name and last name and delete it but findOneanddelete, deleteOne, and findOneandremove are all deleting the documents with the correct first name and last name twice. All these functions are only suppose to delete one document so I am confused why they are deleting two documents.
This is where I am suppose to delete one document it inside the function service.deleteperson.

```
return Person.findOneAndDelete({first_name: data.first_name, last_name: data.last_name}, 
      function(err, response){
          if(err || !response) console.log({message: "Error in deleting "+data.first_name + " "+data.last_name });
          else console.log(response);
   });
```

Comment: Are you sure they are triggered only once?

Comment: I put console.log(data) inside the function and it only printed out the data once.

Comment: I removed return and it only deletes once. why would returning findOneandDelete() making it delete twice?

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this way:

```
Person.findOne({first_name: data.first_name, last_name: data.last_name})
   .then((doc)=>{
    Person.deleteOne({ _id: doc_id }, function (err) {});
});
```